# How to read multiple Integer values from a single line of input in go?

Tags: go

I am working on a program and I want to allow a user to enter multiple integers when prompted.

For example:

Enter multiple integers: 1 3 5 7 9 11

i want it to be stored in a slice

```
[1 3 5 7 9 11]
```

Comment: You know what you want, that's good. Now show us what you tried. This site is not a code generator, it's a place to ask questions when you've tried something and are stuck on a specific, code related problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found my answer

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func numbers(s string) []int {
    var n []int
    for _, f := range strings.Fields(s) {
        i, err := strconv.Atoi(f)
        if err == nil {
            n = append(n, i)
        }
    }
    return n
}

func GetInputSlice() []int {

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    scanner.Scan() // -------------------------------> was missing this before
    return numbers(scanner.Text())

}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Enter sequence of Intergers :")
    var fullslice []int
    fullslice = GetInputSlice()
    fmt.Println("Enter sequence of Intergers :", fullslice)

}
```